# Can an Activity bind to multiple services at once?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application with 2 services.
One service is to display notifications and another to send SOAP request to a webservice.
Is it possible to bind to both services from one Activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, single activity can bind multiple service.

Answer (score 5):

It is the `ServiceConnection` that represents the binding.  In order to bind multiple services, you just need multiple instances of `ServiceConnection`.

For instance, in the extremely unlikely circumstance that you wanted to bind the exact same service, `MyService`, ten times, code like this might work:

```
private final ServiceConnection connections[] = new ServiceConnection[10];
private final MyService services[] = new MyService[10];

private void connect() {
    Context ctxt = getApplicationContext();
    for (int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        connections[i] = new ServiceConnection() {
            private final int idx = i;

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                services[idx] = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                services[idx] = null;
            }
        };
        ctxt.bindService(getIntent(), connections[i],  Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: How you will unbind specific ServiceConnection? I have multiple ServiceConnections bound to Activity and I want to unbind specific one, but couldn't find a way?

Comment: Context.unbindService

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer since it have an explanation on how to do multiple bindings.